# Address value shows null

Tags: java, spring

I have two classes Student and Address which implements IStudent ans IAddress interfaces respectively. Student class has a relationship with Address class. That is why i have declared a reference member of it.

```
public class Student implements IStudent {

    private String code;
    private String name;

    @Autowired
    private IAddress address;

    @Override
    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public IAddress getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


}
```

and I have Address class

```
public class Address implements IAddress{

    private String city;
    private String pinCode;
    private String houseNo;
    private String roadName;
    @Override
    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPinCode() {
        return this.pinCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHouseNo() {
        return this.houseNo;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRoadName() {
        return this.roadName;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public void setPinCode(String pinCode) {
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
    }

    public void setHouseNo(String houseNo) {
        this.houseNo = houseNo;
    }

    public void setRoadName(String roadName) {
        this.roadName = roadName;
    }


}
```

In my applicationContext.xml file i have written the following bean definitions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">  
    <bean id="studentbean" class="main.Student">  
        <property name="code" value="S001"></property>  
        <property name="name" value="Subhabrata Mondal"></property>  

    </bean>  

    <bean id="addressbean" class="main.Address">  
        <property name="houseNo" value="119/2"></property>  
        <property name="roadName" value="South Avenue"></property>  
        <property name="city" value="Delhi"></property>  
        <property name="pinCode" value="110005"></property>  
    </bean>  

</beans>
```

When i have checked Student object after initialization of bean, name and code has assigned with setter method. But the address is not assigned. Thus it shows null value for address. I have marked address with @Autowired annotation. Can you please help?

```
 ApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Student student = (Student) factory.getBean("studentbean");
        System.out.println(student.getAddress());
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly wire to Address not IAddress since the CI only knows Address, if you want to wired

```
  @Autowired
   private Address address;
```

or you need to define a bean with type IAddress but make sure you do not have more than implementation or spring will get confused, if you have more than one implementation use can qualifiers to clear the ambiguity

Answer (score -1):

This whole example is kind of strange but you can get rid of the @Autowired annotation and use following bean configuration instead;

```
<bean id="studentbean" class="main.Student">  
        <property name="code" value="S001"></property>  
        <property name="name" value="Subhabrata Mondal"></property>  
        <property name="address" >
            <ref local="addressbean"/>
        </property> 
</bean>
```